# Нужна ли запятая перед как? "Хочу стать, как ты"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Уважаемые специалисты! Следует ли ставить запятую в предложении *"Хочу стать, как ты!"?*

Answer (score 4):

Не нужна: запятая **не** ставится, если

> ... оборот с союзом как входит в состав сказуемого и предложение без
>   такого оборота не имеет законченного смысла.
>
> Пример: *Девушка держалась как хозяйка.*

http://litmasters.ru/minutka-gramotnosti/zapyataya-pered-soyuzom-kak.html

В нашем случае не имеет законченного смысла глагол "стать".

Answer (score 0):

Что выбрать: ***Хочу стать, как ты.*** Или: ***Хочу стать как ты.***

Фраза **разговорная, характерная для неполного предложения**, отсюда и трудности при решении этой задачи.

1) Конечно, **самый простой и беспроигрышный вариан**т — это использовать формальное правило от Розенталя: оборот не обособляется, если входит в состав сказуемого.

...оборот не обособляется, если **входит в сказуемое (образует именную часть составного сказуемого) или по смыслу тесно связан со сказуемым** (обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без сравнительного оборота): Марья Ильинична сидела как на иголках (П.); Как ребёнок душою я стал (Т.); http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

2) Но всё-таки вспомним, что предложение  это характерно **для диалога, для неполных высказываний,** и тогда возможно такое понимание:

(1) *Я хочу стать как тЫ! Ты добрый и сильный.* Нет паузы, ударение падает только на оборот.

(2) *Ты добрый и сильный. Я хочу стАть (таким), как тЫ.* Делается пауза, ставится два ударения.

Во втором случае указательное местоимение ***таким*** можно восстановить по предыдущему тексту. Такое предложение можно считать неполным.

**Но это запись устной речи, это расстановка логических ударений.** А письменная речь — это другое дело, там формальное правило важнее.

3) **В школьных сочинениях** также можно встретить подобные фразы. К примеру, ребенок описывает свою маму, а в конце делает вывод: хочу стать, как мама. Запятая здесь кажется вполне оправданной, но рискованной (фраза-то разговорная).  Лучше написать: *хочу стать такой, как мама.*

Такая же ситуация с великими людьми, на которых хотят походить дети. Можно описать все достоинства поэта Лермонтова и сделать вывод : хочу стать **таким**, как Лермонтов. Местоимение ***таким*** на письме пропускать категорически не рекомендуется.

Comment: Я рассматривал похожий вариант, но у меня получалось тире: _- Ты хочешь стать трактористом? - Да, я хочУ стать - как ты!_